# What's the best way to handle many paths on a python Tornado server?

Tags: python, tornado, web-frameworks

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/auth/login", AuthLoginHandler),
        (r"/auth/logout", AuthLogoutHandler),
        (r"/auth/register",RegisterHandler),
        (r'/user/([a-z\d.]{5,})/?',UserHandler),
        (r'/user/([a-z\d.]{5,})/friends',UserFriendHandler),
        (r'/user/([a-z\d.]{5,})/status',StatusHandler),
        (r'/user/([a-z\d.]{5,})/wall',WallHandler),
        (r'/actions/respond_friend',FriendActionHandler),
        ]
```

This is my handlers array. This is likely to grow even more.  My question involves the line:

```
    (r'/actions/respond_friend',FriendActionHandler),
```

I plan on using this line to respond to friend requests via post, with the friends username as a post parameter.  How would I retrieve this parameter when I send the post (where is it "stored")?  Does it make more sense to do this:

```
(r'/user/([a-z\d.]{5,})/actions/respond_friend',FriendActionHandler),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_argument`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html?highlight=get_argument#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument) to get a request param inside of your post method

`username = self.get_argument('username', None)`

I don't know if it makes sense to pass the username through the url. If you are it would be duplicating it to post the username as well.

If a url param doesn't match the regex I believe tornado just raises a 404.  So if you need more fine grained control over what errors are raised, it could make more sense to just post the username in the post body

Comment: Right I understand that I don't need to use the username in the post. But if I did it the other way, how would you get the username from the document to put in the post? Do I store it in a value type field. I guess my question would be to how to dynamically generate post parameters?